# Alexa handlerInput.requestEnvelope.context.Viewport undefined

Tags: node.js, alexa-skills-kit

I'm trying to get the `pixelWidth` of my Alexa Spot using `handlerInput.requestEnvelope.context.Viewport` (node.js), but Viewport is always `undefined`.

It used to work until recently. I tried resetting my device to factory default, but that did not work. Any other way to get the dimensions of the device?

Comment: Strange, the way I would normally test Viewport is also not passing it anymore. I'd open a ticket with Alexa support to ask if they have changed it. I don't know any other way to get the device dimensions.

Comment: Is it still being sent in LaunchRequest? If so, could you store it across the session?

Comment: No, Viewport is not available on LaunchRequest.